# Consolidate query results in sql

Tags: sql, impala

I have following data in my table

```
column1 count1
1   2
2   3
2   5
3   4
3   1
4   3
5   4
6   7
7   3
8   0
9   2
10  1
```

Following is the output I want:

```
id  sum(count1)
1   2
2   8
3+  25
```

Following is the query I am using for this :

```
SELECT column1 AS id,sum(count1) FROM test
WHERE column1 < 3
GROUP BY id
UNION 
SELECT '3+' AS id,sum(count1) FROM test
WHERE column1 >= 3
GROUP BY id
```

This is a rather inefficient way because we scan the table twice. Is there a better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need simple `GROUP BY` clause but *conditional* with `case` expression

```
select 
     case when column1 >= 3 then 3 else column1 end AS id, sum (count1) count1 
from table t 
group by case when column1 >= 3 then 3 else column1 end
```

You could explore your desired result with *sub-query* or something similar

Answer (score 0):

A simple formulation in Impala is:

```
select least(column1, 3) as id, sum(count1) as count1
from table t 
group by least(column1, 3)
order by min(id);
```

This does not return the `3+`.  For that, we need to be careful about types:

```
select (case when column1 < 3 then cast(column1 as string) else '3+' end) as id, sum(count1)
from table t 
group by (case when column1 < 3 then cast(column1 as string) else '3+' end)
order by min(id);
```

I also find `order by min(id)` a convenient way to get the result set in the right order.